# How to scroll in Google Contacts using JS?

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to extract my contacts on Google Contacts (https://contacts.google.com) using Javascript. To do this, i need to scroll the contacts panel to the bottom, in order to get the all the page source and then extract my contacts.

Using Devtools i could find the div that has the scroll area would be the one with the 'QkOsze' class like the image below shows. So i'm using the code below to scroll down :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('QkOsze')[0].firstElementChild.scrollTop +=1000;
```

But it's not working, it seem the scroll area is on another div i could not find...

Any ideas please ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the correct one.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('zQTmif SSPGKf eejsDc')[0].scrollTop +=1000;
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Could you explain how you could find the correct one ?

Comment: I just used the select tool in in the browser dev tools, saw the div you were asking about in the question and it was wrapped by `zQTmif SSPGKf eejsDc`.